# How to create a 3D-style button

Tags: android

Hi, I want to make a button in an activity. I have created one, but in 2D [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ2qI.png).

How do I make it in 3D
[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJzD3.png)?

Comment: My Code is     <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Subt One"
        android:textSize="28dp"/>

Answer (score 5):

In the 2D button you're using SDK 4.0 (or it seems to be that one), in the 3D button you're using SDK 2.3.3. Google changed the button style through the different Android releases, moving from a very 3D button in versions from 1.5 to 2.2, then making it more flat in 2.3.3 and now it's 2D in the latest version.

If you want to have your 3D button-like in all Android versions you have to create your own button style, making three [9-patch images](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) (one for button pressed, one for button not pressed and one for button not enabled) and declaring a selector in an XML. I suggest you to follow [this](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/) tutorial to create your custom button.

Comment: well said its the sdk dependence only.. +1 this @Arshay can mark this as answer

Answer (score 2):

see the link below:
http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/

Comment: Dude Tell me how to use that tutorial i.e Do I have to create a new xml file
Where do I save that file and how to add in main activity

Comment: yes, save them as xml in drawable folder and then in your main.xml where you have code for button. write in button properties:
android:background="@drawable/bluebutton" like that.

Comment: and btw, your 2d buttons are from android 4.0 api, so it is 4.0 style. THey are nice ^^

Answer (score 1):

gradient tag allows color gradients in your drawable, you can use it to make 3d-style button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#EAEAEA"
        android:endColor="#979797" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

[check the final effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irua0.png)

Answer (score 0):

it's either an ImageButton http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

or a styled image. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#background

Answer (score -1):

In this post i found a good solution of 3D button:

**layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:gravity="center" tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

**values/dimen.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="corner_radius">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="layer_padding">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**drawable/botao_normal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botao_sombra" />

    <item android:bottom="@dimen/layer_padding">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
            <solid android:color="@color/azul" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**drawable/seletor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/botao_pressionado" android:paddingTop="10sp"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botao_normal" android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
    </item>
</selector>
```

**drawable/botao_pressionado.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item android:top="@dimen/layer_padding">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
            <solid android:color="@color/Azul" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**drawable/botao_sombra.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
    <solid android:color="@color/AzulEscuro" />
</shape>
```

**drawable/botao_normal.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botao_sombra" />

    <item android:bottom="@dimen/layer_padding">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
            <solid android:color="@color/Azul" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package uplicativos.example_3d_buttom;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And the reference :http://www.uplicativos.com/blog/en/2015/11/27/3d-button-in-android-applications/

Answer (score -2):

Create a button in layout xml file like this -

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Click me!" />
```

I ll need to look into your code to assist you properly.

Comment: My Code is <Button android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:text="Subt One" android:textSize="28dp"/>

Comment: Set a background using android:background property. Let the background be a selector. Selector can help you give different backgrounds depending on the different state. Like you can have one for pressed state and one when not in pressed state. does that help?